# Unable to run angular program

Tags: angular

When I run `ng serve` I am facing error like:

> ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zone.js/dist/zone'
>   Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
>   i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Link for the error image: https://ibb.co/6bWBYps

Comment: did u give 'npm i' before ng serve??

Comment: Try this: npm i zone.js

Comment: Yes Gave it already when starting

Comment: @Seba Cherian : That too i done

Comment: Is it not working?

Comment: @Seba Nope I'm getting an error like
********************************************
pm WARN @angular/core@8.0.3 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: Try `rm -rf node_modules` and then a fresh `npm install`. `Zone` is included in Angular CLI so it shouldn't have to be installed manually, so remove that from your `package.json` and let Angular CLI handle it.

Comment: @Daniel: Unable to run the command

rm -rf node_modules
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try 'npm i zone.js@~0.9.1'

Comment: **Don't** install `zone.js`manually, it's included in Angular CLI. Remove your `node_modules` folder manually and reset your `package.json` and then run `npm install`.

Comment: @DanielB seems to fix issue when manually installing 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25288

Comment: Thanks @Sathyanarayana it's working Now :)

Comment: Alright, thanks for pointing that out, but try to include a source when stating things that go against best practice! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the polyfill.ts folder, change the import from

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

To This:

```
import 'zone.js';
```

Read more on the package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/zone.js?activeTab=readme

Note: This is using Angular 9 and "zone.js": "~0.8.26"

Answer (score 0):

Running the command "npm i zone.js" before "npm serve" fixed the issue for me.